# Different threads accessing the same dictionaries (for read only)

Tags: python, multithreading, dictionary, thread-safety, conflict

I have a function (myFunc for e.g.) that takes a start and end date & iterates over it and accesses some dictionaries to process the data for this time period. I am looking to use threads to parallelize this code.

My main() function reads in data from a bunch of files & stores them in dictionaries. Every time I call myFunc I pass these dictionaries and a start & end date. When I call myFunc using multiple threads and pass along the same dictionaries, would there be a conflict? These dictionaries are used only for read-only purposes.

myFunc creates a lot of dictionaries which it then writes out to another file. This output file would differ for every thread, but since across all the threads the dictionaries are named the same, would there be a conflict? Theoretically, I understand that the concept of threading means that there should not be a conflict as long as those dictionaries are not global. But since its my first attempt at threading, would like some confirmation.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Using threading, no, you're not going to have a problem.  You're also not going to achieve parallelism.  The Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) in Python only allows a single thread to process at any time.  If you want true parallel processing you need to look at the multiprocessing module.  It has the ability to actually leverage multiple processors on a machine.

Comment: I didnt realize that. Thanks. If I do use the multiprocessing module, would the answer still be No for both my questions?

Comment: Exactly what he said.  To answer your question directly, _no_, there will be no conflicts.  To answer your question better, you can't achieve parallelism in Python using threads; you need to use [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html).

Comment: @user669815 - The answer will still be _no_ to both questions.  Your approach is correct, you just can't use threads.